# how to implement panning in opengl program android

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0

I am having a program in `opengl es`, in which a cube is getting rotated on user-touch along X,Y,Z axis.

Now I want to implement panning feature for the same (when user touches the cube with atleast 2 fingers--it wil get panned along the axis)...

Please anyone suggest me where do I start, I have searched too much on google stil unable to find any satisfactory example.

My code is similar to the code in API demos application which is by default installed on the emulator in which a cube is shown.

Comment: See SO answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/584463/how-does-zooming-panning-and-rotating-work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Panning can refer to a number of different things in a 3D context, but in general you're just going to be moving the camera around.  This is just a matter of how you set up your modelview matrix; I recommend using some sort of 'lookat' function to calculate this, and simply change your eye coordinate.

For the most natural panning, the coordinate should be modified by multiplying your screenspace displacement vector by your existing modelview matrix with w=0, and add the resulting vector to your eye coordinate.

Comment: hey thnks fr d hint....althou i have developed sum apps in android & ndk also yet m new in ds field of opengl in android...can u help me regardin ds more...in respect of code...thnks fr d advice :)

Comment: @Manroop Unfortunately without a bit more context there's not a lot I could go on. It's a bit more straightforward to provide a sample in GLES 1 where you have gluLookAt available, but in ES2 there's too many different ways you could be doing your matrix management.

Comment: yep...finaly d work is over...successfully implemented d panning feature by the use of glTranslatef(), so when d user swipes d finger the rotating cube position is changed :))

Comment: If you're using glTranslatef() that means that you're using OpenGL ES 1, not 2 - but this question was tagged with ES2.  Using repeated calls to glTranslate, glRotate et al is not recommended due to accumulated precision loss (as well as meaning you're keeping all your state in the GL context and can't recreate it easily/quickly if you need it somewhere else) - you should probably be using gluLookAt since you'll have it available.

Comment: no dude i have tagged my question right...m using ES2, its wrking successfully now. The only thing remaining is to implement the swipe gesture in the android-app, now m lukin fr it..thnks :)

Comment: `glTranslatef()` isn't part of ES2. ES1 and ES2 use entirely different matrix manipulation models - ES1 uses a matrix stack (`glMatrixMode`, `glPushMatrix`, `glPopMatrix`, etc.), while ES2 does them as bound attributes (`glBindAttribute`, `glVertexAttribPointer`). Here's another acid test: are you using shaders?

Comment: ok but i have imported library files as "android.opengl.GLES20" dats y m sayin dat m not using ES1. May be m wrong, still shaders are not being used in this app.

Comment: Right, just importing the ES2 API doesn't mean you're actually using it. I recommend reading an OpenGL ES 2 tutorial for Android if that's something you really need to do. There's nothing wrong with just using ES 1 in the meantime, though - ES1 is much easier to use and gives you a few things for free (like cameras, lighting, and matrix manipulation), although it's also a lot more limited.

Comment: Hi friends , i am also trying for pan in opengl es 2.0 in android. i used for setLookAtM method for panning with touchevent method. when i touch and drag the screen, the screen (surfaceview) need to move like autocad pan option.please help anyone..